# How does Spring @Async choose a task executor/scheduler if multiple ones are defined?

Tags: spring, spring-async

I have the following defined in XML configuration:

```
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10" />
<bean id="asyncExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
<bean id="asyncExecutor2" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
```

When using the `@Async` annotation in Spring, how does it know which of these executors/schedulers to use?  I would expect it to throw an error on startup since there are multiple here and I have not included a `<task:annotation-driven executor="xxx"/>` tag, but it appears to be working fine.  Is there a way I can log somewhere which one is being used?

Comment: Yes you can log inside @Async method to detect thread name

Comment: When I log `Thread.currentThread().getName()`, it just shows `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1`, with the number increasing by one for each invocation.

Answer (score 0):

...

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="asyncExecutor" />
<task:executor id="asyncExecutor" pool-size="10" />
```

...

You might look at the thread name in the stacktrace when debugging, it should start with something like: `[asyncExecutor-xx]`

Comment: When I log `Thread.currentThread().getName()`, it just shows `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1`, with the number increasing by one for each invocation.

Also, is it wrong that I've declared my task executor like this:
`<bean id="asyncExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>`
Instead of using `<task:executor/>`?  How are the two declarations different?

Comment: It shouldn't be wrong, <task:xxx> is a namespace that helps with beans configuration, you would accomplish the same using just <bean ...>, just that it would require more explicit configuration.